# how to enable query result set download option in Hue Presto JDBC by default

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

I am new to Hue and trying to find out is there any simple solution to my requirement.

In Note Book, out of the two options Presto JDBC and Hive, for Hive I am getting the query results download option (csv, etc) by default where as for Presto JDBC, when I run the query,  I am not finding any download option to download result set, that download icon is missing. How can I enable that in Hue for PrestoJDBC also by default?

I have attached screenshots for reference.

[image: Adding Options]

In PrestoJDBC, Download Icon option is missing.

[image: PrestoJDBC Missing Download Icon]

Hive has Download icon option.
[image: Hive with Download Icon]

Comment: This is probably https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-3996

Comment: As per your reference I have gone through those links, it refers some other links, like that I passed through nearly 10 link references but finally I did not get answer to my question. Could you please post solution steps here if you are aware of it.  One way I understood was to change the status to success from availability  but I am not sure is it right solution or in which file I need to  make this change?